# WSO2-ESB-4.8.1-ERROR - AbstractPersistenceManager Unable to handle service initialization. Resource does not exist at path

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm trying to run WSO2ESB manager node `sh /home/ec2-user/wso2esb-4.8.1/bin/wso2server.sh -Dsetup`. But get this errors in log:

> [2015-05-18 12:04:26,644] ERROR - AbstractPersistenceManager Unable to
>   handle service initialization. Service: echo
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
>   Resource does not exist at path
>   /_system/config/repository/transports/https/listener
>
> [2015-05-18 12:04:26,651] ERROR - DeploymentInterceptor Exception
>   occurred while handling service update event. {super-tenant}
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to
>   handle service initialization. Service: echo
>
> Caused by:
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
>   Resource does not exist at path
>   /_system/config/repository/transports/https/listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like either you have not configured the database settings or registry has not mounted properly. Please refer to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Setting+up+the+Database) for more information.